# Hosting a node web crawler?

Tags: node.js, hosting

I've got a crawler which checks a list of URLs every 60s written in Nodejs. It uses no database, stores a few items in-memory and should run 24/7.

What's a proper solution for hosting this crawler?

As far as I've understood AWS it's paid per second which would make a 24/7 process pretty expensive I guess? Or maybe I'm missing something here, the AWS docs are pretty confusing imo.

Comment: How do you use the items stored in memory? Does the data span multiple calls?

Comment: It's actually just getting data (some strings, not much) from the URLs and storing them in arrays. These strings are most likely replaced every loop.

Answer (score 0):

The tool sounds light enough (based on the purpose), so I'd go for a serverless solution to reduce operations footprint: so go for a Lambda function or ECS FarGate. Here's what you'd expect to pay:

For Lambda, assuming 512MB running for 5 seconds @ 0.0000008333 per 100ms:
60 calls * 24 hours * 30 days -> *43200 * 0.0000008333*50* ~= **$1.8 per month**

https://s3.amazonaws.com/lambda-tools/pricing-calculator.html

For Fargate at the smallest footprint: 0.25 VCPU and 0.5GB memory:
*((0.25 * 0.01239249) + (0.5 * 0.00136079)) * 24 * 30* ~= **$2.7 per month**

Use caution with those numbers, just a quick draft. Both options are fairly cheap, but Lambda might be easier to work with plus you indicated that you don't need the items in memory to persist calls.